# awslogsd cannot push to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Can anyone help me figure out how to trace below two aws logs streaming events back to the originating log entry? I looked into agent-state sqlite database and the stream_state and push_state does not really tell me which event's size it's complaining about as I have a bunch of different logs moving to cloudwatch logs.

> 2020-05-18 22:48:31,474 - cwlogs.push.event - WARNING - 17080 - Thread-10 - Truncate event: {'timestamp': None, 'start_position': 0L, 'end_position': 25086781L}, reason: single event exceeds size limit.

I also don't have any idea which of the events are timestamped ahead of time. There is no time drift. The server appears to have correct time.

> 2020-05-18 22:48:39,477 - cwlogs.push.batch - WARNING - 17080 - Thread-10 - Skip event: {'timestamp': 1589842119000, 'start_position': 25087384L, 'end_position': 25088074L}, reason: timestamp is more than 2 hours in future.

Using **awslogs v1.1.4** as well as the **cwlogs plugin**.